# How to scrap a table from webpage using powershell and save in CSV format in a respective folder

Tags: powershell

I have to scrap a table from the webpage https://www.postgresql.org/support/security/
I need to bring the table format data to a specific folder in csv format .

Please let me know how to do this in PowerShell .This csv file will be ingested to Data warehouse for further manipulations.

My code as of now which creates only folder and csv file with no data in it,

## create the target directory including the date like 'Aug 22'

```
                `$destination = 'C:\Temp\{0:MMM dd}'-f (Get-Date)
                $null        = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType 
                Directory -Force
                $outFile     = Join-Path -Path $Destination - 
                 ChildPath 'Demo.csv'

                $url = 'https://www.postgresql.org/support/security/'
                $req =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get

                if ($req.StatusCode -ne 200) {
                    Write-Warning "Error: Website returned statuscode 
                 $($req.StatusCode)"
                }


                # create the target directory including the date like 
                 'Aug 22'
                $destination = 'C:\Temp\{0:MMM dd}'-f (Get-Date)
                $null        = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType 
                 Directory -Force
                $outFile     = Join-Path -Path $Destination - 
                 ChildPath 'Demo.csv'

                $url = 'https://www.postgresql.org/support/security/'
                $req =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get

                if ($req.StatusCode -ne 200) {
                    Write-Warning "Error: Website returned statuscode 
                    $($req.StatusCode)"
                    }
                    else {
                    $req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName('nobr') | 
                    ForEach-Object {
                        
                    } | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -UseCulture - 
                    NoTypeInformation
            



}
```

`

Comment: The idea behind SO is to help people with their own code attempts. Please show yours. In the meantime you can start by reading [Extracting Tables from PowerShell's Invoke-WebRequest](https://www.leeholmes.com/extracting-tables-from-powershells-invoke-webrequest/)

Comment: Not able to find a way .Please let me know the script that pulls data .